# SonarQube completes analysis, but doesn't log results

Tags: sonarqube

[image]I have one project that completes SonarQube analysis, but doesn't log any results to the database. We are using version 5.6.6

### As the analysis finishes I see the following:

```
[INFO] [15:52:11.959] Calculating CPD for 602 files
[INFO] [15:52:12.191] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] [15:52:13.247] Analysis report generated in 884ms, dir size=13 MB
[INFO] [15:52:14.552] Analysis reports compressed in 1305ms, zip size=4 MB
[INFO] [15:52:14.885] Analysis report uploaded in 332ms
[INFO] [15:52:14.886] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse 
http://sonarqube02.a.fsglobal.net:9000/dashboard/index/org.lds.cas:cas
[INFO] [15:52:14.886] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] [15:52:14.886] More about the report processing at 
http://sonarqube02.a.fsglobal.net:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWAE1KyTKz3i6F3PczBl
```

---

I have provided screen shots of the first and second links.
[image: First Link]
[image: Second Link]

Does anyone know why this particular project cannot place its results into the MySql database while other projects have no problem doing so?

Thanks for any assistance you may be able to provide me on this situation.

Doug

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your project screenshot and in the result of the api/ce/task ws, the analysis of your project has failed (scanner analysis is successful but not the compute engine analysis).

To have access to the logs you need to go to the background tasks of your project (you need to have administer permission on the project).

Comment: Julien,  I just added a partial stack trace to my original post. I can see the problem, but I'm not sure what table the description column relates to nor what the data that was trying to be posted was. How can I better determine what I need to do to resolve the problem with this project?  Thanks again for sharing your expertise.

Comment: Looks like it may have failed after Generate Quality gate events when trying to do Persist components if looking at this good run of another project shows flow.
2017.05.24 09:46:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality profile events | time=1ms
2017.05.24 09:46:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality gate events | time=1ms
2017.05.24 09:46:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist components | time=6ms
2017.05.24 09:46:05 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Persist snapshots | time=47ms` What would cause this?

Comment: My first try would be to upgrade to SonarQube 6.7